# Returns fixed cart to original position after scroll down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed shopping cart that works perfectly. On page load the cart is positioned 350px from the top of the page, after scrolling 350px down the page the shopping cart becomes fixed to the page, my problem is the shopping cart on scroll up the shopping cart goes all the way back to the top of the page, instead of going back to its original position.

How do i do that?

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 350) {
                $("#stickycart").css("margin-top", "0","right",$(window).scrollTop());
              
            }
        });
```

```css
#stickycart{
    width: 25%;
    float:right;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top:450px;
    float:right;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    margin-right: 4%;
     
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="stickycart">
            <p id='order'>My Order</p>
            <p id='estimated'>Average Delivery <br>
                <b id='avg'><?php echo $avg_del ?></b><br> minutes</p> 
            <div id="prods_here">
                <!-- PLACE PRODUCTS HERE-->
<?php cart(); ?>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find consistency in your code because `#stickycart` is not present in your HTML. However, this is probably what you want: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqdYVd

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, it is in my code. i just had to double check

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest this, if you have the possibility to use the *shopping cart* as an absolute item:

https://jsfiddle.net/6trq2mg0/2/

CSS:

```
#cart {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  right: 0;
}
```

script:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 350) {
        $('#cart').css({"position" : "fixed", "top" : "0"});
    } else {
        $('#cart').css({"position" : "absolute", "top" : "350px"});
    }
});
```